# Editable datetime grid column save showing error toaster in Laravel-admin

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2, laravel-admin

I have a user grid with an editable datetime column. When i edit and save the date time i am updating the date value in my db using a put method and controller. But after successful save the error toaster is being shown without any message.

Laravel Version: 6.2.44

PHP Version:7.2

Laravel-admin: 1.7

Grid : `$grid->column('send_date', trans('custom.send_date'))->editable('datetime');`

Route : `$router->put('user/{id}','UserController@updateDeclarationDate');`

```
UserController:

function updateDeclarationDate($id)
  {
      $user= User::where('id','=',$id)->first();
      if(!empty(request('value'))){
          $declarationDate = request('value');
          $user->send_date = $declarationDate;
          $user->save();
      }     
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your function has no return value, so toastr automatically thinks it failed.
Try adding a return statement at the end of it:

```
function updateDeclarationDate($id)
{
    $user= User::where('id','=',$id)->first();
    if(!empty(request('value'))){
        $declarationDate = request('value');
        $user->send_date = $declarationDate;
        $user->save();
    }
    return [“status” => true, “message” => “your popup message“, “display” => []];
}
```